Client Certificate Authentication in flutter app
We have a server written in node which creates an https server as follows:
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const pemFilePath = './server.pem';
const pemData = fs.readFileSync(pemFilePath);
const options = {
    key: pemData,  
    cert: pemData, 
    // Request client certificate
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    passphrase: '123456'
};

const server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
      // Some actions
});

The server requires users to provide client certificates in every request. Everything works in the web browser, but we don't know how to deal with it in the Flutter application. For now, we want to focus on Android.
We tried using KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias to get the certificate alias and then using it to read the certificate with that alias using KeyChain.getCertificateChain. Then we call setTrustedCertificatesBytes on SecurityContext. But as far as I know, that's not all we need to do. We should also set the private key by calling usePrivateKeyBytes with the key data encoded, but we are unable to get it in Kotlin and pass it to the dart code. We tried using KeyChain.getPrivateKey but it returns null.
Certificates are installed as .pfx files on Android phones as VPN and App User Certificate.
How can we achieve this in flutter?
